# Should we close the question, "I love a girl and I want to marry her, but my family refuses her" (11200)?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Should the question [Do I need to obey my family regarding who to marry and who not to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11200) be closed for being primarily opinion-based?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's picked up a useful and interesting answer, and that can be to the benefit of the site if the question is edited to make it primarily about the Islam-related issues *in the answer*.

I will suggest an edit and maybe others who understand better will improve on what I do.

Comment: [(Discussion in chat.)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17879802#17879802)

Answer (score 1):

Should the question be closed, yes.  Should it be closed as primarily opinion-based, no.  The question should instead be closed as Off-Topic (Islam SE: Not an Muslim Peer Support Group).

The question itself is good and very relevant to the subject of Islam, but not everything about the subject of Islam can fit on this site or the SE module.  I do see a good question in it around the subjects of marriage, rights, and family, but as it is now it cannot be salvaged without changing the whole question.

As i see it, the person is unhappy with his family and seeking support, which this site is not for, but should go to local scholars or Imam.  And because this site isn't a support group, the question in my view should be closed as Off-Topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this question should be closed for being primarily opinion-based. It question is ask nothing in relevant to the subject of Islam.

On a related note I found [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/11202) answer to have some reasonable and worth having around advices/principles (be it under this question or some other on created in order to accommodate this answer).